# executing command as su

Tags: ssh, sudo, su

I am executing this command as `su`. I have made the connection with `SSH` (using sshNet), and then when I try to set the command `su -`, I get no response. I have the password and the command I would like to execute after signing in as `su`.

My code, which I know is wrong, for now looks like this:

```csharp
using (var sshClient = new SshClient("10.10.8.113","ems", "ems"))
{
    sshClient.Connect();
    sshClient.CreateCommand("su -").Execute();
    sshClient.CreateCommand("123456").Execute();
    sshClient.CreateCommand("EmsMenu.sh");
}
```

I read about implementing, using Shell, but I didn't manage to succeed in that way.

Comment: If you try to execute a normal command (one that doesn't require `su`), does it work?

Answer (score 4):

The reason this is failing is that, by default, `ssh` does not create a terminal (a `pty`) on the target machine. This means that `su` cannot prompt for a password, so it fails. (`sudo` would also fail to prompt, for the same reason, unless given the `-S` flag - as pointed out by @Scott.)

1. You can tell `ssh` to create a terminal (`pty`) on the remote system, so that `su` can prompt for a password. With a normal command you would do this by providing the `-t` flag to ssh. Unfortunately I cannot offer you any help with the method to do this with [SSH.NET](https://sshnet.codeplex.com) because its documentation is provided in CHM format, which I cannot open.
2. You can cut out the `su` part entirely by connecting to the remote server with the desired target user account, "root". For security reasons this may fail on some systems that refuse root logins that attempt to use a password, so you may want to investigate certificate based logins. A suitable certificate could be generated with the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.

Comment: [The `SshClient` class](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/SSH.NET/Renci.SshNet/SshClient) has methods `CreateShell()` and `CreateShellStream()`. Maybe that's what's needed?

Comment: @Svick, indeed. Maybe.

Comment: Another option is to run `sudo` with the `-S` option, which tells it to read the password from the standard input, even if it's not a terminal (`tty`/`pty`).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use `sudo` before the command you want to execute? Like instead of:

```
su
whatever command
```

do:

```
sudo whatever command
```